# How to decide which of two groups of variables is more correlated?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, multivariate-analysis

Given two groups of random variables {x_1,...,x_n} and {y_1,...,y_n}, and M samples of each group.  I want to determine which group variables are more correlated internally. For example, if the first correlation matrix contains elements that all close to 1 or -1, and the second correlation matrix contains elements close to 0, then the first group of variables are more correlated. I have tried to use the variance of the set of nondiagonal elements of correlation matrix. This method is stable, but needs larger batch size(M). Another method is to compute the total correlation of fitted Guassian and the isotropic Gaussian prior. This method is sensitive for most cases. But for some problem where the data does not subject to Guassian prior, this method performs bad.

So, what I really need is a metric which uses a scalar to evaluate how much a set of random variables are correlated to each other.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Which group is more correlated to what? Do you mean which of the M samples has the strongest correlation?

Comment: Hi Dave, I want to determine which group variables are more correlated internally. For example, if the first correlation matrix contains elements that all close to 1 or -1, and the second correlation matrix contains elements close to 0, then the first group of variables are more correlated.

Comment: What’s wrong with doing exactly what you described?

Comment: In fact, I have tried to use the variance of the nondiagonal elements of the correlation matrix to determine which group is more correlated. But I guess that there may be more advanced method to use a scalar to metric the correlation matrix in the whole.

Comment: Maybe you are asking for [tag:canonical-correlation]?